# Xdebug stopping without breakpoint

Tags: php, phpstorm, xdebug, behat, mink

I'm experiencing a really weird problem.

My Setup:
- Windows Host
- VMWare Vagrant Box with Debian and the project mounted via VMWare share.
- PHP 5/7 mixed environment.

Debugging works fine from the CLI when executing a Symfony command. When executing a Behat/Mink test, it breaks at first line if I tell him to do via PhpStorm's "Break at first line" option.

However, no matter if I set a breakpoint or not, the debugger session seems to halt somewhere ... there is no information shown other than that the debugger is connect to PhpStorm. It remains like this forever till I stop the PHP debug session. When the session is stopped in PhpStorm, the Behat test continues to run.

I nearly tried everything (using php 5/7 ...) but I have no clue why it just stops without break points.

Xdebug remote log also does not reveal anything interesting ...

I hope someone has any idea or hint.

Comment: Have you tried rebooting your Vagrant Box, your own machine, your IDE? Sometimes I had this problem with PHPStorm, it stopped on old breakpoints and reboot was the solution. If it doesn't work, create a new project and move your sources inside it. Hope It will help :)

Comment: Based on your description: 1) you seem to have configured xdebug in a way so it tries to debug every single request 2) you may have "Force break at first line when a script is outside the project" option enabled or similar to that 3) It might be doing more than 1 debug session at the time (e.g. your test creates sub-request/new process which is a separate session for xdebug. to sum it up -- screenshots with PhpStorm's settings + your xdebug config are needed.

Comment: Thanks for the comments :)

I didn't restart my host machine yet but I will that.
Except that I reboot everything, cleared every cache, ...

LazyOne:
1) PHPStorm is configured to require a specific KEY and not listen for every connection
2) Nope, that option is not enabled
3) I allow 5 simultaneous requests

I'll try reboot my machine and if that does not work I'll post screenshots of my config

Comment: @MollocH  What was the solution?